# htaccess and potentially causing duplicate content

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working on a site that has all of its pages indexed in Google yet none of the pages are ranking. The site was shifted to 100% https a while back and I suspect there might be some sort of duplicate content issue as a result of the htaccess code. Here is the code I inherited:

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteBase /       
#
#Redirect to wwww.example.com       
#rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]     
#Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]        
#       
#Remove the index.php after domain.com/index.phpl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on   
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,nc]   
rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[c-t]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]     
Rewriterule ^(.*)index\.php /$1 [R=301]     

ErrorDocument 404 /404Error.php

#Begin Redirects

#FOR DIRECTORY REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?p=11&?
RewriteRule ^exampleblog/$ http://www.example.com/new-york.php? [R=301,L]

RedirectPermanent /about.html https://www.example.com/about.php
RedirectPermanent /example-video.php https://www.example.com/
RedirectPermanent /brooklyn.php https://www.example.com/kings-county.php
```

It's a static website and the htaccess is producing some odd results such as https://www.example.com/about.php/index.php

I'm trying to get the code cleaned up so that it directs all pages to the https version of the url, for example, https://www.example.com/, and not create duplicate content or any other issues for that matter. Thanks in advance to anyone who might be able to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add some `L` flags to your redirect rules up top so that the rewrite engine won't continue to execute rules further down. Second, the `RedirectPermanent` is a different module (mod_alias) and will make it so both mod_rewrite and mod_alias get applied *to the same request*. So use just mod_rewrite instead:

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteBase /       

#Remove the index.php after domain.com/index.phpl
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on   
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,nc,L]   
rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[c-t]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/ [NC]     
Rewriterule ^(.*)index\.php /$1 [R=301,L]     

ErrorDocument 404 /404Error.php

#Begin Redirects

#FOR DIRECTORY REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?p=11&?
RewriteRule ^exampleblog/$ http://www.example.com/new-york.php? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^about.html$ https://www.example.com/about.php [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^example-video.php$ https://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^brooklyn.php$ https://www.example.com/kings-county.php [L,R=301]
```

You also have a non-SSL rule stuck in there, dunno if that's intentional or should be HTTPS:

```
#FOR DIRECTORY REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &?p=11&?
RewriteRule ^exampleblog/$ http://www.example.com/new-york.php? [R=301,L]
```